# How to prevent all products of JetBrains from checking ignored files in the background and make it possible to commit

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I've used several products of JetBrains. If I don't disable the git plugin in WebStorm (or IDEA), the IDE would always keep checking for ignored files.
[image: impossible to commit, and the tasks dont end]
How to solve this problem?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by saying "stuck at checking for ignored files?" Would it be possible to share more screenshots? You may add those files to .gitignore, this article can be helpful https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839-How-to-manage-projects-under-Version-Control-Systems

Comment: I've updated my description. .gitignore has already been properly configured( ignore dependencies such as node_modules , venv and things like that).

Comment: It seems that you could face an issue like here:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-259254

It's hard to say what exactly seems to be an issue without logs, so feel free to submit a support ticket: https://www.jetbrains.com/support/